# Resolving System.IO.IOException: Read-only file system when trying to write logs to AWS

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, docker-volume

On docker-compose, I have set my the `read_only` flag on my project to `true`. Now, however the application is failing on writing logs to AWS because of the error `System.IO.IOException: Read-only file system`. How can I still log to AWS while setting the `read_only` flag to `true`?

I have tried adding volumes on my docker-compose file that points to the logs and allows write access from the logs.

As suggested from .Net documentation I added,
`ENV DOTNET_EnableDiagnostics=0` in my DockerFile